# android BLE 4.0 and 4.1 / API to detect BLE level

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

On Android, when writing an application requiring bluetooth Low Energy, in the manifest, we use the tag uses-feature android.hardware.bluetooth_le.
But how do we check if the device can run BLE 4.0 or BLE 4.1?
When programming for smart watches, how do we know if the smart watch can support 4.1?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what Bluetooth 4.1 feature is applicable to the app developer that isn't in Bluetooth 4.0?

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the Improved Data Transfer

Bluetooth 4.1 devices can act as both hub and end point simultaneously. This is hugely significant because it allows the host device to be cut out of the equation and for peripherals to communicate independently.

For example, whereas previously a smartwatch would need to talk to your phone to get data from a heart monitor, now the smartwatch and heart monitor can talk directly saving your phone’s battery and then upload their compiled results directly to your phone.

Comment: I don't think you can check the ble version. I guess you have to write a test connection to check to see if your feature works or not.